# Pandas: update dataframe using rows as index but keeping original index safe

Tags: python, pandas

i want to know if there is a fastest method to update dataframe using rows as index but keeping original index safe.

My working method:

```
df = DataFrame( { "name":  ['SEBASTIEN', 'JOHN', 'JENNY'] , "age": [39, 34, 32], "city": ['denver','chicago','los angeles'] } )
updt = DataFrame( { "firstname":  ['JOHN'] ,  "age": [42] } )

>>> df
   age         city       name
0   39       denver  SEBASTIEN
1   34      chicago       JOHN
2   32  los angeles      JENNY

df['index'] = df.index    
df.set_index('name', inplace=True)
updt.set_index('firstname', inplace=True)
df.update(updt)
df['name'] = df.index
df.set_index('index', inplace=True)

>>> df
       age         city       name
index                             
0       39       denver  SEBASTIEN
1       42      chicago       JOHN
2       32  los angeles      JENNY
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple merge and combine_first. Much faster than direct indexing. You can also specify `left_on` and `right_on` rather than renaming if you wish.

```
In [28]: result = pd.merge(df,updt.rename(columns={'firstname' : 'name'}),on=['name'],suffixes=['_l','_r'],how='outer')

In [29]: result
Out[29]: 
   age_l         city       name  age_r
0     39       denver  SEBASTIEN    NaN
1     34      chicago       JOHN     42
2     32  los angeles      JENNY    NaN

In [31]: result['age'] = result['age_r'].combine_first(result['age_l'])

In [32]: result
Out[32]: 
   age_l         city       name  age_r  age
0     39       denver  SEBASTIEN    NaN   39
1     34      chicago       JOHN     42   42
2     32  los angeles      JENNY    NaN   32
```

Comment: to keep original index, i have add right_index=True as merge parameters.

Answer (score 0):

This totally depends on relative sizes of the two frames; on certain situations this may be fast enough:

```
>>> i = updt['firstname'].isin(df['name'])        # updt indexer
>>> lookup = df['name'].tolist().index            # look-up function
>>> iter = map(lookup, updt.loc[i, 'firstname'])  # iterator
>>> j = np.fromiter(iter, dtype='int64')          # df indexer
>>> df.loc[j, 'age'] = updt.loc[i, 'age'].values
```

you will not need `i` indexer if you already know all `firstname`s are already in `df`.

Alternatively,

```
>>> sorter = np.argsort(df['name'].values)
>>> i = np.searchsorted(df['name'].values[sorter], updt['firstname'])
>>> indexer = df.index[sorter[i]]
>>> df.loc[indexer, 'age'] = updt['age'].values
```